# How do you translate "Extinction Rebellion" to Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

First I thought this was about human extinction, but then I learnt is was out of concern of other species' survival. "Eksterma Ribelado"?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_Rebellion

Answer (score 2):

What about *Ribelo kontraŭ Ekstermiĝo*?

Answer (score 1):

If you accept *estingiĝo* as an adequate translation of *extinction*, then I would suggest *Ribelo kontraŭ Estingiĝo*, or, shorter, *Estingiĝo-Ribelo*.

I believe *Estingiĝa Ribelo* is not a very good translation, because it could mean that the rebellion itself is extinguishing.